# what does it mean to be symmetric for tensors and Kronecker delta symbols and help explain this answer to me

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition, kronecker-delta

[image]

i understand how to change 2 tensors into Kronecker delta symbols but unsure how they managed to transform back to just one. If someone could add all the steps to get to the answer that would be amazing :)

Comment: Do you know about (anti)symmetric matrices?

Comment: no but I do know about matrices in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the replacement property:
\begin{align*}
(\delta_{ad}\delta_{be}-\delta_{ae}\delta_{bd})\varepsilon_{efa}
&=\delta_{ad}\delta_{be}\varepsilon_{efa}-\delta_{ae}\delta_{bd}\varepsilon_{efa} \\
&=\delta_{be}\varepsilon_{efd}-\delta_{bd}\varepsilon_{afa} \\
&=\varepsilon_{bfd}-0,
\end{align*}
since, if an index is repeated, the Levi-Civita symbol is zero.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!